# GridView not populating with images

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to connect to a site, parse the images on the site using `Jsoup`, save each image as a `Bitmap`, then display all of these images in a `GridView`. Upon selecting an image from the `GridView`, the image should appear in an `ImageView`.

However, all I am getting is a blank screen upon running my code (with a toast showing up).

Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
package com.example.homework18;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView img;
    final private int REQUEST_INTERNET = 123;
    List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, REQUEST_INTERNET);
        } else{
            downloadSomething();
        }

        final ImageSwitcher imgSwitcher = findViewById(R.id.imgSwitcher);

        imgSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                ImageView imgView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                imgView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams imgLayoutParams = new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                imgView.setLayoutParams(imgLayoutParams);
                return imgView;

            }
        });

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                imgSwitcher.setImageResource(images.indexOf(position));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }
    private void downloadSomething() {

        //String imgurl = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-us_u2PBLSOI/UqgPMh7ovjI/AAAAAAAACdI/ujdyGregs6Y/s1600/amazing-butterfly-hd-image.jpg";
        String texturl = "https://www.csuohio.edu/";

        //new DownloadImageTask().execute(imgurl);
        //new DownloadTextTask().execute(texturl);
       new DownloadTextTask().execute(texturl);

    }
    private void getWebsite(String html) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements imgs = doc.select("img");
        int num_of_imgs = imgs.size();
        String img[] = new String[num_of_imgs];
        int i = 0;
        for(Element x : imgs){
            String url = x.absUrl("src");
            img[i] = url;
            i++;
        }

        for(String url : img){
            Bitmap image = DownloadImage(url);
            images.add(image);
        }

    }
    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = download(URL);
        if(in != null) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.d("NetworkingActivity", e1.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private class DownloadTextTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return DownloadText(urls[0]);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getWebsite(result);
        }
    }

 private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return DownloadImage(urls[0]);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            //ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            images.add(result);
            //img.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    private String DownloadText(String URL)
    {
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
        InputStream in = download(URL);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int charRead;
        String str = "";
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        try {
            while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
                String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                str += readString;
                inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Networking", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return "";
        }
        return str;
    }
    private InputStream download(String URL) {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            return in;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.d("NetworkingActivity", e1.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream in = null;   int response = -1;  URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        }  catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Networking", " " +ex.getLocalizedMessage());  throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) { context = c; }
        //---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount() { return images.size();  }
        //---returns the item---
        public Object getItem(int position) { return position; }
        //---returns the ID of an item---
        public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }
        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(images.indexOf(position));
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="511dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridview"
        android:id="@+id/imgSwitcher"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you successfully able to connect to the site? Are you successfully querying data with jsoup, are you successfully able to download image as bitmap? Please go into more detail on what you've done to debug your code so we can get a better idea of where you are going wrong :) Cheers.

Comment: thank you for helping me take a step back. the images from DownloadImage are all null. I will have to take a look at that method.

Comment: Sure :) I hope to see you figure it out. Please do reply if you need any help

Comment: private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return DownloadImage(urls[0]);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            //ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            images.add(result);
            //img.setImageBitmap(result);
        } its an issue with this class now where i have to call the method in an async task but its not adding the bitmap to images. any ideas?

Comment: i added the code in the OP so it's easier to read

Comment: in your `Mainfest.xml` file, do you have these permissions `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: yes, I need to somehow take the gridview code and put it into the onPostExecute method of the DownloadImageTask, but I do not know what to replace with this for my ImageAdapter